# How to set page settings for PhantomJS in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide, phantomjs, driver, ghost

The title says it all, I am currently trying to use PhantomJS with Eclipse and it works, but however I don't know how I can change the settings for PhantomJS's custom page settings and I would like help with it. Thankss

```
DesiredCapabilities dcaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
dcaps.setCapability(
        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
        phantomjs.getAbsolutePath());
dcaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
dcaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,
        new String[] { "--web-security=yes", "--ssl-protocol=any",
                "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes",
                "--local-to-remote-url-access=true",
                "--disk-cache=true"});
PhantomJSDriver phantomdriver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcaps);
phantomdriver.get(someURL);
driver = phantomdriver;
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're using. Are you running phantomjs through selenium?

Comment: Yes I am running phantomjs through selenium in Eclipse.

Comment: I only know how to change the settings in the command line thou :l

Comment: OK, so what settings are talking about? Something like user agent string or something else?

Comment: YES!!!! Something like that, primarily the page settings. Is there a way to implement that into eclipse?